# problems with running hellogridview from android.com

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have posted a question before about this now I have no errors but when I try to run my app on my simulated android device it comes up with an error that says

> sorry the application Hello Grid View
>   (process com.HelloGridView) has
>   stopped unexpectedly. Please try
>   again.

Here is the file tree the files will follow later:

```
HelloGridView  
src  
com.HelloGridView  
HelloGridView.java  
ImageAdapter.java  
gen  
Android 2.2  
assets  
res  
drawable( with all the pics)
```

HelloGridView.java

```
package com.HelloGridView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloGridView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.HelloGridView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public ImageAdapter(HelloGridView c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove these lines from your ImageAdapter class everything will work.

```
public ImageAdapter(HelloGridView c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

This constructor is getting called and your Context is not getting set. I'm not a Java expert but I assume it is getting called because it is more specific.

You already have this constructor which will handle setting up the context.

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}
```

Another solution is to change your existing constructor to this and it will work too.

```
public ImageAdapter(HelloGridView c) {
    mContext = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this line in the tutorial 
"Save the image files into the project's res/drawable/ directory."

In your project you dont have this folder but instead /drawable-hdpi  (ldpi...etc.)

so solve it , just create new folder under the res directory and call it "drawable" and import your images to that folder.

OR

in the AndroidManifest.xml update the line "@drawable/icon"  to your folder.